# Android Detect space in given String and break line

Tags: java, string, split

Just a quick question, as after an hour of research I haven't yet found a solution to my problem:

I have a **given String** (from online DB) that **may contain spaces** and I need to **break the line at every space**.
**The output must be a String**

Could someone help please?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll(" ","\n");
```

Comment: Yep, works. Thanks!! I was lost in regex and stuff like "split("\\r?\\n")".
I can accept your answer right now (as the system doesn't let me do so for the first 10min) but will very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this for e.g.

```
String s = I am a dragon.
s.replaceAll(" ", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split It

```
class A{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "Hello Hello Hello Hello ";// Now Your String like This 

    String arr[] = word.split(" ");// You can Split it from every Space 

    for (String name : arr) {
        System.out.println(name);// output is a String
    }
}
```

}